# Pip uninstall leads to Owned by OS

Tags: 14.04, pip

I am trying to uninstall django and pip itself using pip, but when I type

```
sudo pip uninstall django
```

or

```
sudo pip uninstall pip
```

I get the response

```
Not uninstalling pip at /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, owned by OS
```

I have found plenty of work-arounds on similarly posted question on this website and other websites by manually deleting the folder or using apt-get, but can someone please explain what is causing pip to not uninstall the packages when I use sudo?  What does "owned by OS" mean?  How can I make it so pip can work on these packages?

Comment: It's important to keep track of which method you use to install software. pip, apt, snap, and others can only uninstall software that they installed. For example, pip cannot remove software installed by apt. Never remove software using `rm` that was installed by one of these software/package managers - that just makes things worse.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the problem might be with `django`, but you can't remove `pip` with itself, like you can with `apt`.

You'll need to run `sudo apt-get remove pip pip3` or, if you want to purge system configurations, `sudo apt-get purge pip pip3` (if you have pip3 installed).

As for django, for which you didn't provide the output, it's possible it's also installable by `apt`, and you can use the method above.

If that's not sufficient for you, you can do something like `sudo find . -name '*django*' -exec rm -rf {} \+`, or so, which will ***remove permanently all files which have `django` anywhere in their name***.